# Alpha Transparent PNG Form too slow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, transparency, alpha

I have problems with transparent form, can anyone help? :)

problem is that its too slow :(
example if i click on button where it should just switch another panel control it takes 3-4 seconds because of redrawing

Class: http://pastesite.com/22086

On Form: http://pastesite.com/22087

so at form load is called `redraw()` and if i click on a button and panel is switched i again call `redraw()`

form load 6 second
switching panels 3-4 seconds

thank you

Comment: I trust there's a special corner reserved in program hell for code that doesn't use comments where required and gets the comment text completely wrong in the few places where they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol i have to always answer to my questions! :D

ok i found a way by adding another form over it :)